# Fail to create a directory for Laravel project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: laravel, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, command-line, terminal

I have been stuck here for a long time, may I know where did the process goes wrong and how can I make it work?

[This is the written command and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWFEx.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO ...make use you have installed `php cli` run `php -v` if nothing happen fix that 1st  https://medium.com/@dinocajic/add-xampp-php-to-environment-variables-in-windows-10-af20a765b0ce

Comment: Php is not installed in your machine. Download and install it. You can install Xampp from here https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below things to confirm.

1. Is PHP installed..please check with `php -v`.
2. If installed, is it available in the system environment variable.